# Git is duplicating files on different branches

Tags: git

I am working on a project where I have a master branch and 2 branches created from it. I don't understand the following behavior from Git : when creating (locally) a file on the branchA, the same file appears automatically on branchB (and any file removals / appends) : looks like they are in sync. How to fix the issue?
I expect that the changes are done separately on every branch.
What I am doing step by step:

1. `git checkout branchA`. Here I am creating a file `file1` and filling i with some content.
2. `git checkout branchB`. Surprisingly I see `file1` on this branch too.
   Any file appends/ removals are automatically being replicated between these 2 branches.
   `git status` says (on both branches the same): changes to be commited : new file: `file1.tf`.

Thank you.

Comment: You probably haven't made a commit after creating files, so they never belong to a branch - they just reside in your working tree (and index if you've done `git add`) and persist across `git checkout`s.

Comment: please demonstrate by showing what you are doing and the output of `git status` as you change branches

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear: Please **edit the question** so that it shows what you are doing, and what is happening. Please do not answer request for information with a comment.

Comment: It's definitely what @iBug was saying: You aren't committing your changes to a branch, so the changes stay pending when you switch branches.

Comment: Thank you : commiting the files fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem (write or accept an answer please). For future reference 'show' does not mean 'describe' in context here It means 'copy and paste exactly what you see in the terminal, all of it'.

Answer (score 1):

Git isn't duplicationg anything it's actually not tracking your files since they're not committed. Untracked files are on your disk and aren't handled by git unless you do a `git add yourfile`. After that git will not allow you to switch branch unless you commit or stash the now tracked modifications.